# Optimize Radio Button when huge collection

Tags: html, radio-button, microsoft-edge

I have a huge collection of radio buttons (+400...) and the problem is that in Microsoft EDGE when a radio button is selected it takes a long moment (+15sec) to select it.

After testing I understood that the problem occurs when too much radio buttons with the same name exist.

Would it be possible to optimize it ? Or is it possible to change something ?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

I suggested to use **virtual-scrolling**. That means your browser always show (for example) 20 radio-buttons and other (380+ items) will be in memory. After scrolling other elements will be rendered, and other will be hidden.

```
Have a look here --> https://jsfiddle.net/eu81273/WKJ5z/
```

Comment: Thank you for this approach. The only problem is that, when you select an option, scroll down and then scroll up again the selected option isn't anymore.

Comment: Yes, right. That means you should save selected state in your memory. For example: 1) you selected some value; 2) then scroll down to bottom of a page; 3) in the DOM of this page input doesn't exist, but in memory exists.

And you are able to use this value from a memory.